# Using shortened URLs instead of direct links on media hosting - will this affect site performance?

Tags: url-shorteners, image-hosting, bitly, latency

I'm working on a site project right now and I have a ton of image assets that are hosted on firebase storage - which is effectively a CDN hosting media on SSD's globally.

When referencing the media on the site, however, I can use the firebase link directly to the image asset or, I figured, can go through a link shortener like bit.ly or branch.io (the firm uses this for link shortening) which would allow me to update the images later without having to update the website but instead just update the link the shortened one is pointing at.

I'm wondering though if there is any issue with doing this? I think uptime and latency is possible?

Any other issues?

Is this a really bad idea too?

Comment: Why can’t you just update the images on the same URL? i.e. upload a new image with the same filename

Comment: URL shorteners are not particularly easy to use IMO.    You have to use a web interface to change the location and it has to be done one at a time.   If I were updating my site I could do it with global search and replace, either through a text editor or command line that looks at all the files that power my site.   I could write a script that mass-updates a spreadsheet of changed URLs or just use a pattern match to change a bunch of them.    Unless your site is very hard to edit, using a URL shortener shouldn't make the processe easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any web property resolution involving a third party like a URL shortener will have an impact on performance.

Ref: https://techcrunch.com/2010/03/17/url-shorteners-speed/

The decision to use one or not comes down to cost-benefit analysis. You could use a tool like gtmetrix to measure how the URL Shortener is affecting the speed of the concerned components. If the delay (resolution, latency, etc.,) is negligible compared to the administrative benefit , you should be least bothered.

As a point of note, you may very well try a URL shortening mechanism on your server. For example, if you are using apache, you can use htaccess rewrites to shorten URLs. (However, the specifics don't come under the scope of this question.)